# JPanel only showing one component when added to container

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

Hello all I am having a bit of an issue with this. I created a JPanel and added components to it and then added the JPanel to container. Now when I call this class from main a window pops up but it only displays the first component of the JPanel. Why is it only showing the first item and not all of them? Thanks.

Note: this code is not complete, I am simply trying to figure out why my components are not showing up before moving on to other things, please just address the components issue.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Player extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
       private CardLayout playerCard;
       private JPanel cardPanel;
       public String player1;
       public String player2;

      // Constructor:
      public Player()
      {

        setTitle("Game");
        setSize(300,200);
        setLocation(10,200); 
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                //set up the panel
        cardPanel = new JPanel();
        playerCard = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel.setLayout(playerCard);

                //get player one name
        JLabel p1Name = new JLabel("Player 1 Name:");
        JTextField oneName = new JTextField();

                //get the name for player 2
        JLabel p2Name = new JLabel("Player 2 Name:");
        JTextField twoName = new JTextField();

                //the button to start the game
        JButton start = new JButton("Start");

        //add the components << Why is only the first component shown??
        cardPanel.add(start);
        cardPanel.add(p1Name);
        cardPanel.add(oneName);
        cardPanel.add(p2Name);
        cardPanel.add(twoName);

        contentPane.add("startCard",cardPanel);
        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm really confused about `contentPane.add("startCard",cardPanel);` :S

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the book I am using it states 
"The CardLayout manager displays components added to its container one at a time, using the methods given  Each component is assigned a string name when added to the component, as follows:
Syntax:
Container.add(String_Name, Component);"

Changing it to just contentPane.add(cardPanel); does not make a difference.

Comment: Please re-read your book since you're using the String when adding a component to the FlowLayout-using container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using your layouts correctly. You use the String constant when adding components to the **CardLayout** using component, not the **FlowLayout** using component. And the String constant goes *after* the component in the add method. Please read the layout manager tutorial since this is all explained quite well there. It looks like you're using CardLayout where it shouldn't be used, and this is why you're only seeing one component. In other words, your program is using layouts completely bass ackwards.

In other words, the container that uses CardLayout can only show one component at a time, meaning, since cardPanel uses CardLayout, it can only display *one* component, here twoName will likely be the only thing showing on it.